# SeekBar - thumb and progress not aligned

Tags: android, drawable, seekbar

I am trying to create SeekBar with custom drawables.

```
<SeekBar
       android:layout_width="360dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:id="@+id/customSeekBar"
       android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
       android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
       android:paddingLeft="0dp"
       android:paddingRight="0dp"
       android:thumbOffset="0dp" />
```

Unfortunatelly I am not able to reach the desired behavior.

If I set thumbOffset to 0dp, the thumb behaves correctly on its limits, but it is not aligned with the progress. [thumb and progress not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65sGG.png)

When thumbOffset is not set, thumb and progress are aligned, but thumb can go out of the bar.[out of bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TiMv.png)

Is there a way to make it inside the bounds and also aligned?

Thanks